# Finding marginal pdf and other probabilities from a joint density function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint density:
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases} {\frac{y}{x^2}} &  \text{$0\lt y \lt x
>  \lt2$} \\  {0} &  \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> (a) Give the marginal pdf of $Y$.
>
> (b) Give the value of $P(X >3/2, Y >3/2)$.
>
> (c) Give the value of $P(Y/X >1/2)$.

I am mainly concerned as to whether or not I'm choosing the limits of integration correctly.

(a) $f_Y(y)$ $=$ $\int_y^2$$ y\over{x^2}$$dx$

$f_Y(y)$ $ =$$-y\over2$$ + 1$ $ I_{(0,2)}(y)$

(b) $\int_{1.5}^2 \int_{1.5}^x$$y\over{x^2}$$dydx = 0.0625$

I chose these limits of integration because $y$ must be between $1.5$ and $x$ and $x$ must be between $1.5$ and $2$. However, when trying to do the integration another way, I got a different result:

$\int_{1.5}^2 \int_{y}^2$$y\over{x^2}$$dxdy = 0.5$

Which one is correct, if either, and why is the other one incorrect? After graphing it, it appears that the former would be correct but why is the limits of integration incorrect for the latter?

(c) $P$($Y/X$ $\gt$ $1\over2$) $=$ $P$($Y$ $\gt$ $x\over2$) $=$ $\int_0^2$ $\int_{x\over2}^x$$ y\over{x^2}$ $dydx$ $= 0.75$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is okay.

(b) is also okay, either way, and you are just getting an incorrect result when you perform the second option. Both should be the same:

$$\int_{1.5}^2\int_{1.5}^x (y/x^2)\mathrm d y\mathrm d x = \int_{1.5}^2 (1/2-9/(8x^2))\mathrm d x = \dfrac 1{16}=0.0625$$

$$\int_{1.5}^2\int_{y}^2 (y/x^2)\mathrm d x\mathrm d y =\int_{1.5}^2 (1-y/2)\mathrm d y=\frac 1{16} = 0.0625$$

(c) is okay too.

You have the correct bounds.   You just need to take care with evaluation.

Comment: Thank you. I had calculated both integrals on an online calculator. I guess I inputted the second one in incorrectly, because now I'm getting that both are $0.0625$ in wolfram alpha.